# Getting 'Skipped for Optimization' job state with %complete less than 100 - PWA PS 2010

Tags: 2010, office-web-apps, project-server

I am getting `Job State = Skipped for Optimization for  Job Type = Status Update with %Complete = 16%`... Now this job type shouldn't be skipped for optimization as per the understanding that MS is intelligently skipping duplicate jobs. Moreover there are no pre and post jobs in queue for the same project. What could be the reason here? using PWA PS 2010

Answer (score -1):

Queue skips job for optimization untill you finish editing, publish and check-in project.